# How to get the request URL for a Retrofit object?

Tags: android, retrofit

I need to log the request URL that Retrofit creates. I don't find any getter methods on Retrofit object or web interface that is generated via Retrofit. The following is my code, where I want to log the address of every request:

```
public void onRequestFoods() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Const.BASE_LOCAL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    FoodOrderInterface foodInterface = retrofit.create(FoodOrderInterface.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestFoods:  request url: ");
    foodInterface.listFoods().enqueue(new Callback<FoodResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<FoodResponse> call, Response<FoodResponse> response) {
            List<Food> foods = response.body().getBody().getFoods();
            mPresenter.onResponse((ArrayList<Food>) foods);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<FoodResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            mPresenter.onRequestFailed(t.getMessage());
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Can you use interceptor? Or `Response<>.raw().request().url()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is [http logging interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) the github repo has a straightforward example of how to get it up and running